# Easy method for deploying .sql script to multiple databases on a single instance

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2016, dbatools

I have a `dbscript.sql` file that I would like to have run against roughly 30 databases sitting on a named SQL Server instance. The script is fairly lengthy (1000+ lines) and contains numerous quotes to change to accomodate using MS_ForEachDB.  I had tried a mass ctrl-h replace-all apostrophe's but that just ended up producing other erroneous errors.

I have started down the road of using dbatools and powershell to accomplish this task but I'm wondering if there is a simpler trick to get this script applied to multiple databases at once.

Comment: Check out [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) and note the `-InputFile`, `-ServerInstance`, and `-Database` parameters. It would be best if you posted your code attempts so we can work through them.

Comment: You could do that pretty easily in SSIS. Use a [Foreach Loop Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/foreach-loop-container?view=sql-server-ver15) and put an expression on the initial catalog or connection string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dbatools is a good option as you could put use the pipeline to pass it into a the Invoke-DbaQuery command. An example would be:

```
Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance "server1", "server1\nordwind", "server2" | Invoke-DbaQuery -File "C:\scripts\sql\rebuild.sql"
```